# Get a href value using JavaScript and open it new window

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to do is to get the value of `value` and open it in new window with a specific size using JavaScript.

HTML

```
<a id="LNK" href="##" value="edit2.aspx?ren=<%# Eval("GLR_ID") %>" onclick="clickLink()">RENAME</a>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function clickLink() {
           var myLink = //I need to get the value of `value`
           window.open(myLink,'Rename','height=150px','width=250px');
           return false;
        }
</script>
```

Please correct my grammar, Thank You.

Comment: The `<%#` tags seem to indicate to me that this involves more than just HTML and Javascript. Off the top of my head, though, I don't actually know what serverside language that is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordixon/4HE97/

Pass a reference to the anchor to `clickLink`:

```
<a id="LNK" href="##" value="edit2.aspx?ren=<%# Eval("GLR_ID") %>" onclick="clickLink(this)">RENAME</a>
```

Use `getAttribute` to get the value:

```
    function clickLink(a) {
       var myLink = a.getAttribute('value');
       window.open(myLink,'Rename','height=150px','width=250px');
       return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("LNK").getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get DOM value using `getElementByID().value`

```
document.getElementByID('LNK').value
```

**OR**

You can pass argument into your `onClick` function.

```
onclick="clickLink(this.value)"
```

and in `function`.

```
function clickLink(value) {
var myLink = value;
```

Comment: The window open but no content displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 window.clickLink = function(a) {
           var myLink = a.getAttribute('value');
           window.open(myLink,'Rename','height=150px','width=250px');
           return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution:

```
function clickLink(e) {
  var myLink = e.getAttribute("value");
  window.open(myLink,'Rename','height=150px','width=250px');
  return false;
}
```

HTML:`<a id="LNK" href="##" value="edit2" onclick="clickLink(this)">RENAME</a>`

A working example can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/ohIfaBU/1/edit)